# Diophantine Equations involving primes

Tags: prime-numbers, diophantine-equations

I wish to prove that if $\exists x,y \in Z$ such that $x^2 + 5y^2 = p$ then there cannot exist $a, b \in Z$ such t hat $a^2 + 5b^2 = 2p$. Here p is a prime natural number. I kind of see why this might be true. Here are my ideas so far. Any help in showing why this claim is true will be appreciated.

Assume there exists x,y as stated above. We can assume that they are positive. We see that (x,y) are then the only positive integer solutions to $x^2 + 5y^2 = p$. Assume further that there exists a,b as stated above. Once again, we can assume that they both are positive. Then $a^2 + 5b^2 = 2p$ implies $(\frac{a}{\sqrt{2}})^2 + (\frac{b}{\sqrt{2}})^2 = p$. Now I stuck.

Comment: I see some connection, but I do not know how that helps me prove my claim. Can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, note $p$ is not $2$, so it's an odd prime. Thus, $p$ could be congruent to $1$ or $3$ modulo $4$. However, note that $x^2 + 5y^2 \equiv x^2 + y^2 \pmod 4$. Since squares are congruent to only $0$ or $1$ modulo $4$, their sum can be congruent to only $0$, $1$ or $2$ modulo $4$. Thus, you have

$$p \equiv 1 \pmod 4  \implies p \equiv 1,5 \pmod 8 \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

As such, since $2(1) \equiv 2(5) \equiv 2 \pmod 8$, you have

$$2p \equiv 2 \pmod 8 \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

Squares are $0$, $1$ or $4$ modulo $8$. Thus, $5b^2$ is equivalent to $0$, $5$ or $4$ modulo $8$. The possible combinations are $0$, $1$, $4$, $5$ or $6$ modulo $8$. Thus, there's no combination which sums to $2$ modulo $8$, which is required for $2p$, so there's no $a, b \in Z$ such that $a^2 + 5b^2 = 2p$.

Comment: How is there residue 3?  By my count, out of the nine sums two have residue 0, two with residue 1, two with 4, two with 5 and the last one with residue 6.  The conclusion is not affected but you still shouldn't include residue 3.

Comment: @OscarLanzi Thanks for the feedback. You're right. I made a mistake when I was checking the values, but I've now corrected it.